# Publishing to facebook from WP7

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7

I'm looking to publish information from my WP7 app to the user's Facebook wall. I've been scouring the internet but I can't find any help.

Does anybody know how to get the user logged in and post a status? I'd also like to know how to post a detailed status, say an image and text at the same time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote an open source [Facebook login control for WP7](https://github.com/offbysome/Facebook-WP7-Login-Button) that makes it pretty easy to get an auth token from a user.  The github project has an example.  Once you get an auth token, you can then do an HTTP POST to /me/feed with that auth token.  The [WP7 example in the Facebook C# SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/) does this (and also has code to do the oauth login).